# Unity HDRP - How to draw to render texture without adding a camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

I recently watched a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrAOkMRlvjo&t=235s) for URP about drawing to a Render Texture without adding an additional camera. The technique in the video uses command buffers to do it. I tried following the technique but it doesn't work for HDRP.

I want to render a space in the scene like all of the environment in front (like he renders ParticleSystem in the scene) but without adding a camera.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;



public class CustomRenderTexture : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    [SerializeField] private RenderTexture _renderTexture = null;

    [SerializeField] private bool _clearOnDraw = true;
    [SerializeField] private Color _clearOnColor = Color.white;
    [SerializeField] private float _x, _y, _z, _virtualCameraSize;


private void Update()
{
   DrawTexture();
}
    

private void DrawTexture()
{
    CommandBuffer cmd = new CommandBuffer();

         cmd.SetViewMatrix(Matrix4x4.TRS(new Vector3(_x, _y, _z), Quaternion.identity, Vector3.one));
        cmd.SetProjectionMatrix(Matrix4x4.Ortho(-_virtualCameraSize, _virtualCameraSize, -_virtualCameraSize, _virtualCameraSize, 0.1f, 100.0f));


        cmd.SetRenderTarget(_renderTexture);

        if (_clearOnDraw) { cmd.ClearRenderTarget(true, true, _clearOnColor, 1.0f); }

        Graphics.ExecuteCommandBuffer(cmd);


}

}
```

I know in HDRP, SetViewMatrix doesn't work but I can't find anything to replace it with. I tried using Custom Pass but all functions require a camera. I have a tv screen (with a material that has a render texture on it) that should show the full area in a specific spot outside the house (as if I'm looking at it from the camera). It shows all black right now.

Comment: if you don' necessarily need the command buffer you could probably go through [`Graphics.Blit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.Blit.html) directly?

Comment: @derHugo I’m new to graphics stuff so I apologize if I ask simple questions. How would I use the Graphics.Blit? I know that it has a source and dest texture. But I don’t have the source texture. That’s what I’m sort of trying to create.